# Inequality involving $e$: $\binom{n}{k} < \frac{1}{e}\big(\frac{en}{k}\big)^k$

Tags: inequality, exponential-function, binomial-coefficients, eulers-number-e

$\forall n,k\in \mathbb{Z^+}$, prove that $\binom{n}{k} < \frac{1}{e}\big(\frac{en}{k}\big)^k$ where $e$ is the [Euler's number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant).
I tried my best to solve it and thought of expanding both sides but it helps me nowhere. Also, the $k$th power seems to be clumsy, i cannot reach the conclusion. Please help me!

Comment: Do you mean $\frac{en}{k}$?

Comment: No binomial coeffficient

Comment: I know you are trying to upper bound the binomial coefficient, but I really think the upper bound should say $\frac{en}{k}$.

Comment: No in the question it is in binomial

Comment: What is your definition for $\binom{en}{k}$ where $en$ is not an integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:
$$\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} = \frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)}{k!}\leq \frac{n^k}{k!}.$$
Now we need a lower bound for $k!$. We will use $k! \geq \frac{k^k}{e^{k-1}}$, which you can see the proof of [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Lower_and_Upper_Bound_of_Factorial). Using this,
$$\binom{n}{k} \leq \frac{n^k}{k!} \leq \frac{n^k\cdot e^{k-1}}{k^k}= \frac{1}{e}\left(\frac{en}{k}\right)^k.$$